# Windows Phone textblock fontautosize

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have 4 buttons like this:

```
<Button Name="button1" Tap="button1_Tap">
                <TextBlock Name="odp1Textblock" TextWrapping="Wrap">odpowiedz 1</TextBlock>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="button2" Grid.Row="1" Tap="button2_Tap">
                <TextBlock Name="odp2Textblock" TextWrapping="Wrap">odpowiedz 1</TextBlock>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="button3" Grid.Row="2" Tap="button3_Tap">
                <TextBlock Name="odp3Textblock" TextWrapping="Wrap">odpowiedz 1</TextBlock>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="button4" Grid.Row="3" Tap="button4_Tap">
                <TextBlock Name="odp4Textblock" TextWrapping="Wrap">odpowiedz 1</TextBlock>
            </Button>
```

I want to have the same fontsize in all these textblocks (with multilines). Can I do this? I tried using Viebox, but then each textblock has different fontsize. I create textblocks content in pageLoaded event.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom button style in page resources:

This style will be applied to each button on the page.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

For a specific button:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
```

---

```
<Button Name="button1" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" />
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: But I want to adjust fontsize depending on text size. If I set static fontsize, some content may do not fit in textblock in button

Comment: @petros What is the difference between font size and text size?